# What experiments and data have validated that the EM field contributes to the gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I've studied GR but no experiments or data come to my mind.

Comment: I don't know if we have such data, either. I believe that the precision tests for the equivalence principle should be sensitive enough to include the electromagnetic field energy as behaving equally to all other mass-energy, but I don't think we can give reasonable direct limits for the contributions of the EM field to the gravitational stress-energy tensor. I might be wrong and it's a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Well EM would be a strange beast if it was deflected by a gravitational field, yet did not contribute to it. Deflection has been experimentally verified, at first by Sun - starlight experiments almost 100 years ago.

Since we have deflection of light, conservation of energy and momentum would mean that the Sun, would also have to move ever so slightly toward the light ray - which *is* gravity.

The conservation of energy and the equivalence principle along with the light bending data are good enough for me. YMMV.

Comment: yes, but what about fields themselves ? the question is perhaps related to the energy of the vacuum

Comment: Not an answer -- does not provide an experiment that directly shows what the OP wants.